# ALFContact joomla plugin used want to edit that page

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

i am working on a website already built in joomla and ALFContact form plugin is used for contact us page. i want to add some information on that page but cannot find any option to edit that page. (i've asked for edit the content only). As i hav'nt use joomla befor it's bit problem for me. not found any help on ALFContact plugin site. 
The page is not present in article manager so i can edit them.
here is the Screen shot of page.

---

[image]

---

want to make changes in text. so help me out if any one used this plugin in any way.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Specifically changes in which text?

Comment: @Elin the text mentioned as bold.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to edit the form was:

- Delete underlined code to detele field "From" (De:)

[image: Delete code for delete -From-]

Before:

[image: With -From-]

After:

[image: Without -From-]

To add custom optional fields: Componets > ALFContact manager

[image]

And you got

[image: Result]

(Youtube) [Install and basic config ALF contact module](http://youtu.be/0AKZmlqh6yw)

Aditional, the language can change on "Language manager" of the site

(sorry for my english)

[joomla](/questions/tagged/joomla) [joomla3.x](/questions/tagged/joomla3.x) [joomla-extensions](/questions/tagged/joomla-extensions)